# React-select and axios issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios, react-select

This is probably related to me not understanding how (very strange) JavaScript works, but I really don't understand why this is the case. I have this piece React/React-select code, almost verbatim from the react-select readme:

```js
  class Status extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          selectedOption: null,
        }
        this.statusOptions = [];
    }
    handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.statusOptions);
            axios.get(host+'/StatusList')
                .then((response) => {
                    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.status_list.length; i++) {
                        this.statusOptions.push({value: response.data.status_list[i][0], label: response.data.status_list[i][1]});
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) =>{
                    console.log(error)
                })
                .then(() =>{

                });

    }
    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (
            <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={this.statusOptions}
            />
        );
    }}
```

This does not populate my react-select list: However, moving the list/array initialization to `componentDidMount` makes it work. Why??

```js
  class Status extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          selectedOption: null,
        }
    }
    handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.statusOptions = [];
        console.log(this.statusOptions);
            axios.get(host+'/StatusList')
                .then((response) => {
                    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.status_list.length; i++) {
                        this.statusOptions.push({value: response.data.status_list[i][0], label: response.data.status_list[i][1]});
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) =>{
                    console.log(error)
                })
                .then(() =>{

                });

    }
    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (
            <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={this.statusOptions}
            />
        );
    }}
```

Comment: Wait sorry, which piece of code works? Shoudn't the first block work?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it would be to initialise a `statusOptions` property in the state of the React component, and then populate it in the Axios call happy path so the `setState` method triggers a re-render filling up the select component.

```
class Status extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: null,
      statusOptions: []
    }
  }

  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get(host+'/StatusList')
      .then((response) => {
        const statusOptions = []

        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.status_list.length; i++) {
          statusOptions.push({value: response.data.status_list[i][0], label: response.data.status_list[i][1]});
        }
        this.setState({ statusOptions })
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedOption, statusOptions } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={statusOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an error in the above code in the JSON object in the CTOR, shoud be ':' not '='. And still with this change, the react-select component is not updated.

Comment: You were right, I had a pair of typos. Thank you for pointing them out.